# Break axis with gg.gap in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, break, yaxis

I am stuck with R. I want to represent changes on gene expression overtime in R. I am using ggplot function, and as some of the values are very high, I used gg.gap to break the y axis, and it breaks it nicely, however, a black like where the gap is, appears and it seems there are to separated graphs. Could someone help me?

Here below is my code and the graph:

```
GSTU7_roots_plot <-ggplot(GSTU7_roots, aes(Time, Average , shape = Treatment, color = Treatment)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Treatment), size =2) + geom_line(aes(color= Treatment), size =1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= Average-Sd, ymax= Average+Sd), width=3, position = position_dodge(width = 0.05))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = c(0,1,6,24,48), limits = c(0,NA)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, NA))+ 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73"), labels = c("IDF", "FFA", "IDF+FFA", "IDF(24h)+FFA"))+ 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,16,17,18), labels = c("IDF", "FFA", "IDF+FFA", "IDF(24h)+FFA")) +
  labs(title = "GSTU7 expression in roots", x="Time (hours)", y= "N-fold") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 3))


GSTU7_roots_gap <- gg.gap(plot=GSTU7_roots_plot, ylim=c(0,250), segments= c(50,90), vjust = 0, tick_width = c(10,50),
                    margin = c(top = 1, right = 2, bottom = 1, left = 1)) +
  add.legend(plot = GSTU7_roots_plot, margin = c(top = 1, right = 1, bottom = 1, left =460))


GSTU7_roots_gap
```

[image]

Thank you (I am not sure I paste the image!)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try again without the `, axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")` in your code. The first `theme()` would then change to:

```
+ theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank())
```